# Error when start erlang application (relx) release

Tags: erlang, release, relx

When I try to start erlang release prepared by `relx` it crashes with reason:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{badarg,[{erl_prim_loader,check_file_result,3,[]},{init,get_boot,1,[]},{init,get_boot,2,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
```

Directory listing:

```
    ├── bin
    ├── lib
    │   ├── asn1-2.0.2
    │   │   ├── ebin
    │   │   ├── priv
    │   │   └── src
    │   ├── bear-0.8.1
    │   │   ├── ebin
    │   │   └── src
    │   ├── cache-1.0.0
    │   │   ├── ebin
    │   │   ├── priv
    │   │   └── src
    │   ├── cberl-1
    │   │   ├── c_src
    │   │   ├── ebin
    │   │   ├── include
    │   │   ├── priv
    │   │   └── src
    │   ├── compiler-4.9.2
    │   │   ├── ebin
    │   │   └── src
    │   ├── cowboy-0.8.6
    │   │   ├── ebin
    │   │   └── src
....................
    │   ├── crypto-3.0
    │   │   ├── ebin
    │   │   ├── priv
    │   │   │   └── lib
    │   │   └── src
    └── releases
        └── 0.5.2
```

All libraries on it's own places.

I tried to start application with the command `erl -env ERL_LIBS ../libs -erlconto` and it successfully started.

It seems, that problem in boot file, but i don't know how to approach this problem.

Any tips or way to solve, please.

Tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added

```
{extended_start_script, true}.
```

to relx.conf an application now work!

Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when OTP application's `.app` file is missing a required dependency. relx uses the contents of `.app` to resolve dependencies to go into the release.

Make sure all of your release applications include, at least, `kernel` and `stdlib` in the `applications` tuple in `.app`.

Here is an example `.app` file listing `kernel`, `stdlib`, and `elk` as dependencies:

```
{application, prop, [
  {description, "Prop Template Generator"},
  {vsn, "0.0.1"},
  {registered, []},
  {applications, [kernel, stdlib, elk]},
  {modules, [prop, prop_otp, prop_generator]},
  {env, []}
]}.
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! All dependencies relx sucessfully copied to lib/ folder (as shown at directory listing). And if i start application manually (without bootfile, but with set ERL_LIBS), it started.